# Duplicate rows in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, duplicates, tidyverse

I have a `data.frame` which looks like so:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c("001","002","003","004"),year=c(2015,2015,2015,2015),
                 x1=c(15,20,25,30),x2=c(1,2,3,4))
    
id   year   x1   x2
001  2015   15   1
002  2015   20   2
003  2015   25   3
004  2015   30   4
```

I would like to duplicate `id`, `x1`, and `x2` but change the `year` to end up with a `data.frame` that resembles the following:

```
id   year   x1   x2
001  2015   15   1
002  2015   20   2
003  2015   25   3
004  2015   30   4
001  2016   15   1
002  2016   20   2
003  2016   25   3
004  2016   30   4
```

I can achieve this by doing

```
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(year = 2016)

df3 <- rbind(df, df2)
```

But I am wondering if there is a more intuitive way, so that I can create duplicates for 20+ years without needing to make multiple new `data.frames`?

Comment: Can I ask why, as this seems like a possible XY-problem?

Comment: I am not too sure I understand what you mean @mhovd.

Comment: I was asking what is the motivation behind the question - what method or problem did you want to solve with this approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```r
df <- data.frame(id=c("001","002","003","004"),year=c(2015,2015,2015,2015),
                 x1=c(15,20,25,30),x2=c(1,2,3,4))
library(tidyr)

df %>% complete(nesting(id, x1, x2), year = 2015:2016)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#>   id       x1    x2  year
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 001      15     1  2015
#> 2 001      15     1  2016
#> 3 002      20     2  2015
#> 4 002      20     2  2016
#> 5 003      25     3  2015
#> 6 003      25     3  2016
#> 7 004      30     4  2015
#> 8 004      30     4  2016
```

For extra years you just need to change `2015:2016` according to your need.  You may also use dynamic referencing here using `seq`

Comment: Great use of nesting

Comment: Thanks @AnilGoyal, I accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(id=c("001","002","003","004"),year=c(2015,2015,2015,2015),
                 x1=c(15,20,25,30),x2=c(1,2,3,4))

map_dfr(0:1, ~mutate(df, year = year + .x))
#>    id year x1 x2
#> 1 001 2015 15  1
#> 2 002 2015 20  2
#> 3 003 2015 25  3
#> 4 004 2015 30  4
#> 5 001 2016 15  1
#> 6 002 2016 20  2
#> 7 003 2016 25  3
#> 8 004 2016 30  4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>